# Creating multiple instance of a view

Tags: sencha-touch

Using Sencha Touch ver 2.3.1a

The carousel control in PassDownEntryView

```
{
    xtype: "container",
    itemId: "pageEntryItemsContainer",
    layout: "fit",
    items:
    [
        {
            xtype: "carousel",
            itemId: "carouselItems",
            direction: "horizontal",
            items:
            [
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm creating multiple instances of a view for a carousel

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
var itemViewArray = [];


var index = 0;
Ext.Array.each(data.Data, function(item)
{
    var itemView = Ext.create('MCConnect.view.PassDown.PassDownEntryItemView');
    itemView.setItemId('EntryItemId' + index);
    itemView.configureEntry(item);

    itemViewArray.push(itemView);
    index++;
});

if(itemViewArray.length > 0)
{
    carouselControl.setItems(itemViewArray);
}
```

configureEntry sets the html in the PassDownEntryItemView

```
{
    xtype: "label",
    html: ""
}
```

Code that sets the label:

```
configureEntry: function(item)
{
    var fieldLabel =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label')[0];
    fieldLabel.setHtml("<div style='text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'><span>" + item.item + "</span></div>");
}
```

It creates the right number of carousels but only the first instance has the label set. The rest of them are blannk.  I did an output of configureEntry() and 
it is properly passwing each item.  Seems like im missing something when setting it. Any ideas?

**Update: 6/21 - A**
It seems like the problem is the instance of the view.  Cause When I create a hard coded view:

```
var item1 = 
{
    item: "test1"
}               

var itemView = new MCConnect.view.PassDown.PassDownEntryItemView();
    itemView.configureEntry(item1);

var item2 = 
{
    item: "test2"
}               
var itemView1 = new MCConnect.view.PassDown.PassDownEntryItemView();
    itemView1.configureEntry(item2);

carouselControl.setItems([itemView, itemView1]);
```

I still get the result that only "Test2" shows even though there are two carousel panels showing up.  Except the second one is blank

**Update 6/22**
Ive added my PassDownEntryItemView code below:

```
Ext.define('MCConnect.view.PassDown.PassDownEntryItemView', 
{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'passdownEntryItemView',
    requires: 
    [ 
        'Ext.data.Store',
        "Ext.field.Text",
        "MCConnect.view.Commons.AutoHeightTextArea"
    ],
    config:
    {
        itemId: '',
        isReadOnly: true,
        passDownEntryItemId: 0,
        layout: "vbox",
        items:
        [

            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                style: 'padding: 0; margin: 1px;',
                items:
                [
                    {
                        xtype: "label",
                        html: ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        listeners:
        [
        ]
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
    },

    configureEntry: function(item)
    {
        this.setPassDownEntryItemId(item.passDownEntryId);
        var fieldLabel =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label')[0];
        fieldLabel.setHtml("<div style='text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'><span>" + item.item + "</span></div>");
    }


});
```

**6/22**
Thanks to Akatum suggestion.  I figured it out.  I labeled the itemId of the label as #labelDistrictItem-0 so in my configureEntry() i searched for it then set it and renamed the itemId:

```
var fieldLabel =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('passdownEntryItemView #labelDistrictItem-0')[0];
fieldLabel.setItemId('labelDistrictItem-' + item.id);
fieldLabel.setHtml("<div style='text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'><span>" + item.item + "</span></div>");
```

and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `configureEntry` function. `var fieldLabel =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label')[0];` will always returns first label component in your whole application. So in your case it will always returns label which is in your first carousel panel.

Instead of using `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label')[0];` you should look for specific label in specific `MCConnect.view.PassDown.PassDownEntryItemView` by using [`up()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-up) or [`down()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-down) methods (depends on layout of your application).

#### Edit

You can get your `label` component by looking for it only in child components of your `PassDownEntryItemView`. For this you can use [`down()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-down) method. So your `configureEntry` method should look like this:

```js
configureEntry: function(item) {
    this.setPassDownEntryItemId(item.passDownEntryId);
    var fieldLabel = this.down('label');
    fieldLabel.setHtml("<div style='text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'><span>" + item.item + "</span></div>");
}
```

**Fiddle with working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6t4**

Comment: Ok, that makes allot of sense thanks.  I posted my PassDownEntryItemView above can you give me a tip on your solution.  I  understand what your saying but since its the same view everytime i'm not quite sure how to attempt to look for a specific label.  Could I give it a different itemId when first create it?  But if I set the label via Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label')[0]; it will still find the one created

Comment: You are creating multiple instances of your `PassDownEntryItemView` view. Each instance has its own child components. I've updated my answer based on your layout and add example. Your solution with item ids is also possible.

Comment: OK, I see what your doing.  Thanks for the help.